# Duplicated Memory on .NET using two lists

Tags: c#, .net, sortedlist

I'm working on a small app on .NET, I need to point the same data with 2 diferent lists, I'm wondering if perhaps the memory is duplicated, for example

```
public class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;

    ....
    public Person(name, age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

SortedList<string> names;
SortedList<int> ages;

Person person1 = new Person("juan",23);

names.add("juan",person1);
ages.add(23,person1);
```

I guess that .NET as Java will not duplicate the object Person, so it will be keeped, so if   I do this:

```
names("juan").age = 24
```

Will change the object in both lists.

Is it right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Person` is a class, you are only putting a *reference* into the list, so each list will have a reference *to the same person*. The `Person` object will indeed not be duplicated, and `names["juan"]` will de-reference the original object.

However! That doesn't make the code faultless:

- there might be more than one person aged 23; `SortedList<,>` won't like that
- changing the age via `names["juan"]` won't automatically update `ages`; `ages[24]` will fail

If `Person` was a `struct`, then the `Person` **would** be copied every time you assign it (but: this is not a good candidate for a `struct`; don't do that)

Answer (score 1):

To test reference equality, you can always do:

```
bool equals = ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2); 
//in your case, obj1 = names["juan"], and obj2 = ages[23]
```

If reference is the same that means any change on it will be reflected on variables that reference to the same object.

---

In your case, yes they are just the same reference in both lists.. So if you do anything on the reference, be it on `person1`, `names["juan"]` or `ages[23]` it will be reflected everywhere. That said, your collection should look like:

```
Person person1 = new Person();
SortedList<string, Person> names = new SortedList<string, Person>();
SortedList<int, Person> ages = new SortedList<int, Person>();

names.Add("juan", person1);
ages.Add(23, person1);

//names["juan"].age
//ages[23].age 
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This Will change the object in both lists.

if you want to provident this i suggest to overload the "=" operator (explicit )

Comment: How would overriding the operator help? there isn't anywhere where that is being used

Comment: Thank you, I just working with lists of great size, and I was afraid of they will duplicate data. I only use that class for example, my real object is more complex.

Comment: to make a copy constructor!

Comment: @user2004810 no, you can't do that in C#

Comment: Actually I want to be the same object in two different lists

Comment: Yes i can, look over here:[http://omegacoder.com/?p=124](http://omegacoder.com/?p=124)